# "We have to put up new skyscrapers in the downtown."

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it possible (and natural) to say so?:

> We have to **put up new skyscrapers** in the downtown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is natural to say or write:

> We have to put up new skyscrapers.

It is possible to say "We have to put up new skyscrapers in the downtown." but this usage of "in the downtown" is awkward at best. It would be natural to say:

> We have to put up new skyscrapers downtown.

Here downtown functions as an adjective, rather than a noun.